# How to eliminate the space above Section in SwiftUI Form?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I wanna eliminate the space above the first `Section` in a `Form`

[image]

```
 var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Text 1")
            Form {
                Section {
                    Text("Text 2")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to set the frame of the Section's header to 0, but it does not work

Comment: Why should you set header to 0? If not need then you can use `List`

Comment: @SagarChauhan I need a Form, the Sections below will have headers and footers, but I do not need a header for the first Section in the Form

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is to add a `Section` with an `EmptyView()`, and then put the view you want at the top inside the `Section`'s header.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Text 1")

        Form {
            Section(header: VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                Text("Text 2")
                    .padding(.all, 16)
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, alignment: .leading)
                    .background(Color.white)
            }) {
                EmptyView()
            }.padding(.top, -6)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats a quite hacky solution...

Comment: Adding negative padding changes the clickable regions, too. So not a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution may depend on your requirements. What worked for me was an empty Text view as in:

```
  Section(header: Text("")) {
    MySectionView()
  }
```

BTW, I tried EmptyView() but that is ignored completely; as in the space still remains.

Answer (score 0):

I'd supply a dummy header view and set its size to be zero:

```
Section(header: Color.clear
                .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
                .accessibilityHidden(true)) {
  Text("Text 2")
}
```

Comment: This does reduce the space somewhat but not any more than for example providing an empty text view (`Text("")`) as header. There will still be some unnecessary space left and reducing the frame of the dummy header seems to have no further effect.

Comment: You are correct @araxias. But I’d rather do that than some UIKit hack.

Answer (score -4):

This is much simpler:

```
struct ContentView: View 
{

    init() 
    {
        UITableView.appearance().tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: Double.leastNonzeroMagnitude))
    }

    var body: some View 
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: This is an entirely WRONG answer because this will set it application-wide! This should not be the accepted answer!

Comment: @wadda_wadda you're correct, but you can always reset the header to its default size by calling `UITableView.appearance().tableHeaderView = nil` wherever you need it back. Setting the appearance in the locations where it's needed is totally acceptable and common practice.

Comment: "Setting the appearance in the locations where it's needed is totally acceptable and common practice" - Yes exactly, that's why this answer is not a good solution, as it sets the appearance for all locations, not just where it is needed.

Comment: @wadda_wadda just add `.onDisappear { UITableView.appearance().tableHeaderView = nil }`